# Facebook open-graph - publish action reliability

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Can anyone tell me, what is the reliability of Facebook's open graph API when publishing actions to the timeline?

**Background**:

- I've created a new FB iOS App
- Create a new action type "write" with custom object "blogpost" as the generic types don't work for me
- Followed every single bit of the tutorial provided by Facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ to conform to all the OG requirements

**Publishing code**:

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me/MY_APP:write" andParams: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject: @"http://blogpost.url/here" forKey: @"blogpost"] andHttpMethod: @"POST" andDelegate: self];
```

Following is the blogpost page head snippet conforming to the OG requirements:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# MY_APP: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/MY_APP#">
      <title>Blogpost page</title>
      <meta property="og:title" content="Blogpost page" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="http://url.to/the/image.png" />
      <meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456790123456789" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://blogpost.url/here" />
      <meta property="og:type" content="MY_APP:blogpost" />
</head>
```

**Testing environment**:

- Tested in simulator as well as the actual device
- For every request attempt, I do a fresh app starts to exclude any app's network issues.
- Every time, my request is exactly the same, with the same linked blogpost url.
- I'm using the latest iOS SDK available
- My network is perfectly reliable
- The blogposts pages are accessible and correctly contain all the requirements set by opengraph

**The error responses from Facebook API vary each time:**

- OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
- Exception: Could not retrieve data from URL.
- Exception: Object at URL 'http://blogpost.url/here' of type 'MY_APP:blogpost' is invalid because the domain 'blogpost.url' is not allowed for the specified application id 'XXXXXXXX'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXX.

(NOTE: Obviously, blogpost.url is being replaced with a real existing page)

The requests success rate is somewhere around 30%.

Is it possible there're any issues on the Facebook's end? Currently, I don't feel like publishing my app in the current shape of Facebook sharing reliability.

Thank you for any feedback, help or advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further research and patience, everything works reliably now.

The following errors just stopped appearing within 24 hours, without any change of code at our side (I suppose there was indeed an issue at FB):

- OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
- Exception: Object at URL 'http://blogpost.url/here' of type 'MY_APP:blogpost' is invalid because the domain 'blogpost.url' is not allowed for the specified application id 'XXXXXXXX'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXX.

The following exception was caused by our action object's url - as the url went live literally a second before the "FB publish action", the URL wasn't really published across all the instances of our web frontend:

- Exception: Could not retrieve data from URL.

Hope this helps someone in the future.